# How to iterate over an object of queryset if the object contains more than one character and spaces?

Tags: django, django-views

I tried to sort the string that was input through form by converting to list,but I am getting the error that the object is not iterable. How do I sort it without the inbuilt method ?

**models.py**

```
class LinkedList(models.Model):
    post = models.TextField(max_length=256)

    def __str__(self):
        l1=list(self.post.split(" "))
        return str(l1)
```

**views.py**

```
def listform(request):
    form = LLForm(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)

        list1 = LinkedList.objects.all().last()
        listll=list(list1)
        for i in range(1, len(listll)):
             key = listll[i]
             j = i-1
             while j >= 0 and key < listll[j] :
                 listll[j + 1] = listll[j]
                 j -= 1
             listll[j + 1] = key

        cont={'ll': listll}
        return render(request,'basicapp/linked.html',context=cont)

    else:
        form = LLForm()
        return render(request,'basicapp/listform.html',{'form':form})
```

Comment: What exactly is this code supposed to be doing? Are you trying to order things manually? Why?

Answer (score 0):

Your query set not seems correct.

You need to change your queryset as following:

```py
from django.db.models.functions import Length
qs = LinkedList.objects.annotate(post_len=Length('post')).filter(post_len__gte=2)
```

This `queryset` will give you what you want.
You can order it however you can:

```py
my_list = list(qs)
for l in my_list:
    # Do Comparison Here
    # l will be LinkedList instance.
```